# Sending Filter Selections as an Object to Return Multiple Values in Angular App

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, javascript-objects

I have a function in my Angular app that takes in user selections of various filter types, and then sends out a request to the API which then returns the data filtered according to those user selections. Each filter type returns values as an array, because, for instance, for a filter type like "location", the user might select both "New York" and "Los Angeles", in which case this would be the result:

`location: ['New York', 'Los Angeles']`

The filter selections are being passed into the component like so:

```xml
<div class="page-content">
    <table-display [records]="records"
        (sendLocation)="onFilterReceived($event, type = 'location')"
        (sendLanguage)="onFilterReceived($event, type = 'lan')">
    </table-display>
</div>
```

I have set up these filters as an object, so that I can return multiple values rather than just one -- because, after all, if the user makes a filter selection for a certain language, and they also filter the results by location, then I need to pass both of those filter values in the request.

However, right now, with my current implementation, when I console log the object I am still only getting values for one of the filter types at a time, (either language or location) depending on what was the most recent one that had a value change.

What am I missing here? How do I need to tweak this code to be able to keep (i.e. persist) the values for both filter types? Is the issue that I need to explicitly return the object? Do I need to break out the gathering of the values of the two different filter types into different functions? Something else?

Bottom line: I need to be able to pass the current filter selections for BOTH language and location, but right now only one at a time (the most recent one changed) is persisting.

```ts
private onFilterReceived(value: any, type: string) {
    let filtersObj = {
        language: '',
        location: ''
    };

    if (value && type === 'lan') {
        filtersObj.language = value;
    } else if (value && type === 'location') {
        filtersObj.location = value;
    } 

    console.log('filtersObj: ', filtersObj); // Currently only returns the most recent 
                             // filter selection, either language or location.
                             // I need the values for BOTH.

    // TODO Later: Collect all filter values and pass to API for filtered data
}
```

Just to make it crystal clear what's happening, right, now, if a user chooses 'Spanish' from the language filter, this prints to the console:

```
filtersObj:  {language: Array(1), location: ""}
```

And if you expand the array in the console, it's:

`language: ['Spanish']`

If the user then chooses 'New York' from the location filter, the language value is lost and I see this:

```
filtersObj:  {language: "", location: Array(1)}
```

And when I expand to see the array in the console I see this:

`location: ['New York']`

So again, right now I'm only getting one at a time: language OR location. But I need *both* values.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The key is the use of the `this` keyword. First, just initialize the filters in your component to return an empty string -- this will allow your initial API call to return all results:

```
language: any = '';
location: any = '';
zipcode: any = '';
branch: any = '';
```

Then, change your `onFilterReceived()` function to this:

```
private onFilterReceived(value: any, type: string) {
    if (value && type === 'lan') {
        this.language = value;
    }
    else if (value && type === 'location') {
        this.location = value;
    }

    console.log('filtersObj: ', {language: this.language, location: this.location});
}
```